# Java Collection Type Parameter to array

Tags: java, class, generics, java-8, abstract-class

I want to create a helper method which gets `Collection` type parameter to return a list. This is what I have now:

```
public class Helper {
    public static <T> T[] CollectionToArray(Collection<T> collection) {
        return collection.stream().toArray(Object[]::new); // Error
    }

    public static <T> T[] ListToArray(List<T> list) {
        return list.stream().toArray(Object[]::new); // Error
    }
}

public class IamSoNoob {
    public void PleaseHelpMe() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        String[] arrayFromList = Helper.CollectionToArray(list); // Error
        String[] arrayFromSet = Helper.CollectionToArray(set); // Error

        String[] array = Helper.ListToArray(list); // Error
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to complete `CollectionToArray(Collection<T>)`?

   - If so, how?
   - Also, is it possible to pass `List` and `Set` as a parameter in the first place?
2. Is it possible to complete `ListToArray(List<T> list)`?

   - If so, how?

But here are some restrictions due to my personal taste.

1. I don't want to use `@SuppressWarnings`
2. I really want to keep the part `.stream().toArray(Object[]::new)` (Java 8 part!)

And I have a feeling that I need to fix the part `Object[]::new` by using something like: `<T extends Object>` or `<? extends T>` but I can't really figure out.

Please help me out, and please provide an explanation as well, I am often confused by `Generic` and `?`.

Comment: If it were possible to construct an array from a generic type alone, `Stream.toArray()` wouldn't require any parameters.

Comment: @shmosel Right, but I'd like to know the solution for my question

Comment: You'll need to accept another parameter. Either `T[]` or `IntFunction<T>`.

Comment: @shmosel How about the unchecked assignment `(T[]) collection.toArray()` ?

Comment: @nullpointer That's begging for a ClassCastException.

Comment: @shmosel Could you provide an example code please?

Comment: Just copy the parameter from `Collection.toArray()` or `Stream.toArray()`.

Comment: Whats the bad thing in just using `Collections.toArray(T[ ])`? Why don't you just do `String[] arrayFromList =list.toArray(new String[0]); ` ? Whats the reasoning behind writing your own methods when the standard libraries provide tested , trusted and well doing exactly what you want methods?

Comment: @Ryotsu It can be `String` or `Integer` or `Double` ... I want to make the method as generic as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you absolutely cannot do it, if it were possible the library method `Collection.toArray()` would've given you the same type as your LHS but instead when you want the exact type as your LHS you have to use `Collection.toArray(T[])` (even that comes with `ArrayStoreExceptions` i.e it is up to the programmer to provide the right type for the array), the reason being that in your `toArray()` you've specified `Object[]` to be your array and later you cannot cast it to any other type or else it will result in a `ClassCastException`.

The reason for all this hullabaloo is because of the way generics works i.e its a compile time thing and at runtime Java erases all type parameters to their upper bound types and hence losing type information which is required for creating arrays.

One safe way of doing it is by adding another paramter to you helper method as

```
public static <T> T[] CollectionToArray(Collection<T> collection, T[] arr) {

            return collection.stream().toArray(value ->Arrays.copyOf(arr,collection.size()));


        }
```

and using it as

`String[] arrayFromList = Helper.CollectionToArray(list, new String[0]);`

but then everybody's better off using
`Collection#toArray(T[])`.

Comment: I removed my old answer since it's wrong - thanks for the answer :)